# Как делается разделение на потоки в игровом движке?

Tags: многопоточность, разработка-игр

Интересуюсь структурой игровых движков, и в связи с этим возник вопрос по поводу многопоточности.

Как мне известно, в любой игре есть игровой цикл, внутри которого происходит пересчет координат, столкновения, перерисовка и т.д., поэтому я думаю - не работает же все в одном потоке... Какие модули, либо части физики, пересечений, отрисовки, или вообще поведение врагов игре, работают в другом потоке?

Для примера возьмем игру гонки на машинах (простая трасса, есть финиш, есть боты, соперники). Может кто-нибудь подробно опишет, что и как, или подскажет где найти подходящую информацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все зависит от реализации и требуемой производимости.

Простой игровой цикл выглядит так:

1. Обработать логику
2. Обработать физику
3. Отрисовать графику

В зависимости от сложности игры и требований к ней эти стадии могут быть разбиты для выполнения в потоках. Однако следует учитывать, что интегрировать физику невозможно до тех пор, пока не будет просчитана логика, т.е. нельзя двигать машину, пока мы не определили, жмёт ли игрок на педаль.

Я бы для многопоточности определил **три** случая, когда её можно использовать:

1. На стадии отрисовки графики. Да, в главном потоке мы будем рисовать все на экран. Саму отрисовку графики на несколько потоков не разобъешь из-за последовательности отправки команд на GPU, и у нас будут простаивать остальные ядра процессора. Мало того, и это ядро будет не полностью нагружено, нагружена будет шина и GPU. Поэтому тут мы можем считать что-то ещё, пока рисуется графика.
2. Когда вычисления можно делать не последовательно. Как в случае с физикой. Если на многоядерном процессоре мы разобъем все на несколько потоков, выиграем в скорости, и при этом ничего не потерям, так как каждое определение и разрешение столкновения не зависит от другого.
3. Когда нужно выполнять длительную операцию. Вот загрузка игры, к примеру. Часто игры, когда грузятся, "виснут". Это из-за того, что какая-то часть загрузки происходит в том же потоке, что и графика. Понятное дело, на экране может ничего не появляться несколько секунд, пока в оперативную память с диска грузятся модельки машин. Поэтому такая загрузка делается в отдельном потоке, а в основном потоке отрисовывается прогрессбар, показывающий процент этой самой загрузки.

**Подытожим**
Конечно, разбиение на потоки может зависеть от других факторов в зависимости от сложности. Но вкратце это бывает в трёх случаях:

1. Когда есть какие-то нюансы, связанные с тонкостями железа.
2. Когда можно разбить вычисления без ущерба качеству, выиграв в производительности засчет многоядерности.
3. Когда необходимо выполнять несколько длительных задач в реальном времени, так как пользователь следит за прогрессом всех сразу.

Если здесь что-то неверно или есть неточности - не стесняйтесь писать в комментарии или править ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень индивидуально. В общем случае - берите свой игровой цикл и смотрите какие части вы можете распараллелить. Какие части вы не хотите блокировать на время выполнения.

Часть вещей почти всегда будет в отдельных потоках и/или предоставлена вам ОС - ввод от пользователя, отрисовка на экран, управление окном приложения.

В случае с простыми гонками, параллелить практически нечего, т.к. все действие происходит вокруг машины игрока и тесно с ней связано (столкновения, физика и т.п.). В случае сложного мира - можно вынести какие-то части в отдельные рабочие потоки (подгрузка ресурсов, расчет ИИ трафика, сеть, и т.п.)